# Why comparing dict and number is not always FALSE?

Tags: python, dictionary, numbers, comparison

Why is dict bigger then any number !!!!

```
In [41]: {} > 11
Out[41]: True

In [42]: {} == 11
Out[42]: False

In [43]: {} < 11
Out[43]: False
```

What can I do to make it work ?

Comment: Upgrade to python 3.

Comment: Yes, this is Python 2 specific behavior, where all objects are comparable. This behavior was later removed